# .htaccess loop issue on 404 files

Tags: php, .htaccess, loops, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I've been reading the manual and this site for guidance, but I need some help.

My current htaccess file does the following:

1. www. is forced
2. php extensions hidden
3. Forward slash is added on root
   and directory files

The issue is that php files that do not exist (404) fall into a PHP loop from .php/ to  / . Not sure how to fix the issue.

Any ideas how to stop the loop on non-existent files?

```
RewriteEngine on 

# CANONICAL URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

#REDIRECT INDEX.PHP TO ROOT
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L] 

#REMOVE .PHP EXTENSION
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]

#ADD TRAILING SLASH 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

#INTERNALLY FORWARD (example: /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

#PAGINATION LINKS
RewriteRule   ^(.*)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)$  $1.php?page=$2
```

Comment: What is an example URL that is causing redirect loop?

Comment: example.com/product-removed.php - renders to... example.com/product-removed.php/ and this is the loop. It only happens on pages that have been removed from the site and do not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line just above `RewriteEngine On`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
```

This will reset any 404 handler set in Apache config.

Test this after completely clearing your browser cache.

**Full .htaccess:**

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
RewriteEngine on 

# CANONICAL URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301] 

#REDIRECT INDEX.PHP TO ROOT
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L] 

#REMOVE .PHP EXTENSION
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]

#ADD TRAILING SLASH 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

#PAGINATION LINKS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/([0-9]+)/?$  $1.php?page=$2 [L,QSA]

#INTERNALLY FORWARD (example: /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I reset cache and added the code above. Still just adds a trailing slash to the non-existent page and falls into the loop.

Comment: Just noticed another snippet at the end of the file that seems to stop the loop when I comment it out, but also breaks the pagination links when removed.

      `PAGINATION LINKS
      RewriteRule   ^(.*)/$ $1.php
      RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)$  $1.php?page=$2`

Comment: This fixed the trailing slash on the 404 pages, but the pagination links are broken. The link needs to look like www.example.com/page/2 , but it is looking like www.example.com/page/2.php/

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Everything is working now.